# Union operation with ctypes doesn't work

Tags: python, ctypes

I have a C struct like this:

```
typedef struct {
    my_domain_type_t type; 
    my_domain_union_t u;
    my_domain_int32_list_t list;
} my_domain_value_t;


typedef struct {
    int32_t min;
    int32_t max;
} my_domain_int32_range_t;
```

C function that I'd like to call from ctypes:

```
int64_t myData::get_min(const my_domain_value_t &value)
{
    int min_value = 0;
    my_domain_type_t dt = value.type;

    if (dt == 0)
    {
        my_domain_int32_range_t range = value.u.range;
        min_value = range.min;
        printf("min_value=%d\n", min_value);
    }

    return min_value;
}
```

ctypes defintions:

```
class myDomainInt32RangeT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ('min', c_long),
                 ('max', c_long) ]

class myDomainUnionT(Union):
    _fields_ = [ ('range', myDomainInt32RangeT ) ]


class myDomainValueT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ('type', c_int ),
                 ('u', myDomainUnionT ),
                 ('list', myDomainInt32ListT ) ]

class myData(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.object = myDataX.myData_new()

    def get_min(self, arg1):
        myDataX.myData_get_min.argtypes = [ c_void_p, POINTER(myDomainValueT) ]
        myDataX.myData_get_min.restype = c_longlong
        return myDataX.mydata_get_min(self.object, arg1)
```

Python code:

```
mydataY = myData()
domainRange = myDomainInt32RangeT()
domainRange.min = c_long(3)
domainRange.max = c_long(5)
domainUnion = myDomainUnionT()
domainUnion.range = domainRange
domainValue = myDomainValueT()
domainValue.type = 0
domainValue.u = domainUnion
domainValue.list = myDomainInt32ListT()
b = mydataY.get_min( byref(domainValue) )
print(b)
```

I'm expecting a value of 3 for min_value but I keep getting 0. The C code also prints 0. Looks like the union doesn't get setup/transferred correctly.

What did I do wrong ?.

TIA,

John

Comment: `c_long` in one, and `int32_t` in the other -- are those the same types on your platform?

Comment: Have you tried printing domainValue.u.min from Python before and after calling the ctypes function, to make sure that it's actually 3?

Comment: @sarnold: Good catch. On a 64-bit platform, it's likely that he ends up with u.min and u.max as the low and high 32 bits of his intended min value, so instead of min(3, 5) he's calling min(3, 0) or (if big-endian) min(0, 3). I'd post that as an answer—even if it isn't actually his problem, it's _a_ problem, and will probably be the most likely reason for anyone else coming here…

Comment: @sarnold: is there a way to check it ?. If it's not what would be the way to do it right ?

Comment: @abarnett: domainValue.range.u does print 3.

Comment: Did I do the passing by reference correctly ?.

Comment: Hrm, on closer inspection, is _this_ the problem? `myDataX.myData_get_min.restype = c_longlong` ? Why `c_longlong` here when `c_long` was used earlier? (Incidentally, I've got no easy suggestion for checking the types except a brute-force storing values such as `0x12345678` into an `int32_t` and reading it back out of the `c_long`.. a bit gross.)

Comment: @sarnold: the return value is int64.

Comment: @JohnX: The most direct way to test is "print ctypes.c_int32()._type_, ctypes.c_long()._type_". This tells you the ctypes packing specifier for each type; on a 32-bit platform they'll probably both be "i", but on 64-bit they'll probably be "i" and "l".

Comment: @JohnX: It doesn't matter what the return value is; that will get cast properly. The issue is that you've defined my_domain_int32_range_t as a struct of two int32_t values, but myDomainInt32RangeT as a Structure of two long values. If long != int32_t, you're constructing a pair of 64-bit ints and trying to pass it as a pair of 32-bit ints, and doing it behind ctypes' back, so it's going to see the first 64-bit int as the pair of 32-bit ints.

Comment: 64 bits.
>>> print(ctypes.c_int32()._type_, ctypes.c_long()._type_)
i l

Comment: That should tell you the answer. int32 and long are not the same type. The fix is to use the same type for members that you want to be the same, so just change it to c_int32. If you want more details, I'll post an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want the myDomainInt32RangeT Structure to be used interchangeably with the my_domain_int32_range_t struct, they have to define compatible types. But they don't:

```
typedef struct {
    int32_t min;
    int32_t max;
} my_domain_int32_range_t;
```

This defines a pair of int32_t values.

```
class myDomainInt32RangeT(Structure):
    _fields_ = [ ('min', c_long),
                 ('max', c_long) ]
```

This defines a pair of whatever long values.

The problem is that int32_t and long aren't the same type. The fix is easy: change one to match the other (e.g., use c_int32 instead of c_long).

If you want to understand why you get 0, that's a bit more involving.

The rules for int32_t say it must be 32 bits. The rules for long say it must be at least 32 bits. On most 32-bit platforms, and on 64-bit Windows, it's exactly 32 bits. On most other 64-bit platforms, however, it's 64 bits. (See the discussion on LLP64 vs. LP64 at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/64-bit for details.)

You're probably on a 64-bit Intel Mac or Linux system, and using the default Python. Therefore, your long, and therefore ctypes.c_long, are 64-bit integers. So, look at the layout of a myDomainInt32RangeT:

```
1st 32 bits: low half of the 64-bit "min" value
2nd 32 bits: high half of the 64-bit "min" value
3rd 32 bits: low half of the 64-bit "max" value
4th 32 bits: high half of the 64-bit "max" value
```

The layout of a my_domain_int32_range_t, by contrast, is this:

```
1st 32 bits: 32-bit "min" value
2nd 32 bits: 32-bit "max" value
```

So, if you construct a myDomainInt32RangeT(3, 5), what you're creating is:

```
1st 32 bits: 3 (low half of 64-bit 3)
2nd 32 bits: 0 (high half of 64-bit 3)
3rd 32 bits: 5 (low half of 64-bit 5)
4th 32 bits: 0 (high half of 64-bit 5)
```

When you try to interpret that as a my_domain_int32_range_t, it sees:

```
1st 32 bits: 3
2nd 32 bits: 0
```

So your "min" value is 3, and your "max" values is 0.

You may also end up slicing objects and/or overwriting memory by passing around things that some code thinks is 128 bits while other code thinks it's 64 bits. For example, if you create a my_domain_int32_range_t, pass it by reference into Python, then try to set its "max" value, you're setting the 3rd and 4th 32 bits of an object that only has 2 of them, which means you're actually overwriting the next object in memory.

The details above assume you're on a little-endian system (like x86_64), as opposed to a big-endian system or something different (are there any VAX-endian LP64 platforms? with Python?). On a PowerMac G5 with a 64-bit big-endian PowerPC build of Python, you'll get (0, 3) instead of (3, 0). But the basic idea is the same.

Comment: It works. I'm not clear about this: "Now, try to interpret that 128-bit struct as a pair of 32-bit ints, and of course you're going to get (3, 0)."  Could you explain more ? Where does the value 5 go ?. Thanks!.

Comment: Well, the first 32-bit int is 3. The second 32-bit int is 0. The third 32-bit int is 5, but you only have two 32-bit int variables, so you don't have anything to look at to see the 5. I'll try to edit the answer to be clearer.

Comment: This is still that C programmers have to deal with whenever they cast pointers, or use unions. Needless to say, it rarely comes up in Python, but when you're using ctypes to pass unions around… Anyway, let me know if anything is still unclear. And if anyone else has a good reference to link to, please add it.